# Centering boxes inside a div (image+text)

Tags: html, css

I'd like to center three boxes like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4gPO2Q50KsZcGxrbGEySFV5eU0/view?usp=sharing

What I want to achieve is to show the boxes one over the another in mobile devices but I do not know how to do so.

I am using this code:

```css
div#alex_box {
    border: solid 1px #aaa;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.img_home {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #0000ff;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
} 

div.img_home img {
    display: inline;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

div.img_home a:hover img {
    border: 1px solid #0000ff;
}

div.img_desc_home {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="alex_box">
<div class="img_home">
    <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="http://dev.lifeonbikes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/depositphotos_18467679-Travel-car-illustration.jpg" alt="primera imagen"></a>
     <div class="img_desc_home">Texto primera imagen</div>
</div>

<div class="img_home">
    <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="http://dev.lifeonbikes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/images.jpg" alt="segunda imagen"></a>
     <div class="img_desc_home">Texto segunda imagen</div>
</div>

<div class="img_home">
    <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="http://dev.lifeonbikes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/bus-icon120413.png" alt="tercera imagen"></a>
    <div class="img_desc_home">Texto tercera imagen</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: _What I want to achieve is to show the boxes one over the another in mobile devices but I do not know how to do so._ - Use `media querys`.

Comment: Pretty much what @Vucko said. By the looks of things the properties of the images are fine, but why you cant see them on top of each other is because their containing div size doesnt change with the screen. So add a media query that defines the size of the containing div and you should be golden

Answer (score 0):

Try this zoom out and in to see the change  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cp3jvtnp/)

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 2000px) and (min-width: 300px){
    img {
        height:100px;
    }
    div#alex_box {
        border: solid 1px #aaa;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    div.img_home {
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #0000ff;
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
    }
    div.img_home img {
        display: inline;
        margin: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    }
    div.img_home a:hover img {
        border: 1px solid #0000ff;
    }
    div.img_desc_home {
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: normal;
        width: 120px;
        margin: 5px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="alex_box">
        <div class="img_home"> <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="http://dev.lifeonbikes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/depositphotos_18467679-Travel-car-illustration.jpg" alt="primera imagen"></a>

            <div class="img_desc_home">Texto primera imagen</div>
        </div>
        <div class="img_home"> <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="http://dev.lifeonbikes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/images.jpg" alt="segunda imagen"></a>

            <div class="img_desc_home">Texto segunda imagen</div>
        </div>
        <div class="img_home"> <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="http://dev.lifeonbikes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/bus-icon120413.png" alt="tercera imagen"></a>

            <div class="img_desc_home">Texto tercera imagen</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @KyleT Yes you are right.........I tested it with chrome mobile view and it worked fine

Comment: I must have deleted my comment by accident.... weird haha anyways i tested your solution using the full page option in your code snippet and it appears to work similar to how the OP's. Just a heads up to refactor your answer a little :)

Comment: Im currently testing in Firefox, there is always something going wrong between browsers right?

Comment: @KyleT yes i tested in chrome mobile view. it displays the result almost equal as in mobiles

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using **`margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;`** within your **parent div** :

```
div#alex_box {
    border: solid 1px #aaa;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding:10px;
    display:table;
}
```

I also added **`display:table;`** to the **parent div** and **`display:table-cell;`** for **each child div**, and it works fine and it's responsive too.

This is [**the working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qmz0s64v/1/).

**EDIT:**

To separate boxes with spaces you just need to add `margin:5px;` to their CSS: Take a look at [**this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qmz0s64v/2/).

Comment: Hey Chsdk, thanks for that! How would you do to add a space between boxes? rgds

Comment: @Alex Simply by adding `margin:5px; ` to boxes class, see the Fiddle in my EDIT.